# Are pronouns listed correctly in this past tense conjugation table?

Tags: местоимения

[image]

Is it me or is this wrong? In the masculine section of this table, isn't it supposed to say он instead of я?

Comment: I would assume they have some variability here on account to person number to avoid turning into robots.

Comment: This table is wrong only because it is sexist - "I" is assumed to be a male.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe there's explanation somewhere to this table, but I think they just didn't bother to list all the pronouns *because there're only so many verb forms in the Past Tense anyway*.

- The listed masculine forms are true for all **я, ты, он**
- The listed feminine forms are true for all **я, ты, она**
- The listed plural forms are true for all **мы, вы, они**
- And only neuter singular stands apart

So all in all 4 verb forms of each verb aspect.

*The main determinants here are not the actual pronouns but the gender and number* ***masculine, feminine, neuter and plural*** (exactly 4 for each verb aspect), the listed  pronouns are mentioned just as an example of each determinant because in themselves they're irrelevant for determining Past Tense verb forms.

If all the listed pronouns are deleted the table will remain correct and exhaustive for the given verb.

Comment: Neuter singular stands apart - in what sense?

Comment: @ach it has its own unique forms, all the rest are shared between several pronouns... neuter 2nd person can be used offensively but i think it's pretty marginal to be taken into account

Comment: Ah, that. You forget poetry. One might speak to the Sun and the Sun might reply :)

Comment: @ach technically yes, i was thinking in more practical terms